# Multilingual App Toolkit translation service broken

Tags: visual-studio, multilingual-app-toolkit

I'm using the Visual Studio extension [MAT 4.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkitv40) on VS2015 to localize some WPF and WinForms applications. As of May 1 (yesterday) the "Generate Machine Translations" feature stopped working. According to the exception message this is because the [MS Translator service has been moved from DataMarket to Azure](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20).

I've tried subscribing to the translation service on Azure (as instructed by the exception message), but I don't think MAT is using the logged in VS user's account. Still doesn't work.

> TranslateApiException: Invalid authentication token. Microsoft DataMarket is retired. Please subscribe to Microsoft Translator, in the Cognitive Services section at https://portal.azure.com. Please visit https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20 to find detailed instructions. : ID=1230.V2_Soap.GetTranslations.4EAC0341

Apparently this move has been planned for some time, so I'm baffled as to why there isn't an update to the Toolkit.

Anybody have any insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for MAT for VS 2017 is current in testing.  The fix is being back ported to MAT for VS 2013 & VS 2015.

Please note that one key change is the need to have a Azure subscription as reported in the announcement.  Setting up the free 2m char as it should cover the major of usage cases.

I will post here when the fix is ready as well as the instructions for connecting the provider to the Azure service.

**UPDATE:** The fix has been posted that uses the user provided Azure subscription.  fixed versions is MAT 4.0.1610 (VS 2015/VS2013) and MAT 4.0.8610.0 (VS 2017).

After installing the update, you will need to supply the provider the access key or you will receive a message with a link to he instructions.  The details are here: https://multilingualapptoolkit.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1167898

Comment: Thanks for the update! In the meantime, I have written a simple console app that translates the XLIFF files generated by MAT, so I'm back in business.