# Multilingual App Toolkit won't translate in VS 2022 Pro - translation key problem?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, microsoft-translator, multilingual-app-toolkit

My colleague and I use VS 2022 Pro (VS), Multilingual App Toolkit (MAT), and Azure Translator service to translate our RESX resources into other languages; all on Windows 10.  This tooling used to work for me; still Works great for my colleague with the same tools.

After a recent rebuild of my workstation, VS works but MAT no longer translates.  Translations in intermediate XLIFF and final RESX files are not generated (despite MAT appearing to run - nothing changes).

Again, this tooling still works for my colleague.

One thing we noticed is the Azure Translator service key might not be being saved between VS restarts.  Other settings can be saved but this key is not.  But this key-save issue might not be relevant as even after supplying the translator key and starting a translation without closing VS - the translation fails to generate.

Very much appreciate your suggestions for what I could try.  Thanks!

P.S. I have seen these SO answers:

- [Why is the Multilingual App Toolkit not generating machine translations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584891/why-is-the-multilingual-app-toolkit-not-generating-machine-translations)
- [Multilingual App Toolkit .xlf file is not updated during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569499/multilingual-app-toolkit-xlf-file-is-not-updated-during-build)
- [Multilingual App Toolkit translation service broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744282/multilingual-app-toolkit-translation-service-broken)